# Can I Update, Edit, Retrieve data from MS Access placed in Share Point using Python?

Tags: python, sql-server, ms-access, sharepoint

I am trying to raise a query from my system to the MS Access file stored in Share Point using Python. I have no idea how to do that. Someone Please help!!

Answer (score 1):

It seems it cant be done
see https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Power-Query/Connecting-to-SQLite-db-stored-in-sharepoint/td-p/1156356 where there is the comment :
"SharePoint libraries do not behave the same as local drives or network shares. Same with Access databases. Access cannot even open its own MDB/ACCDB files in SharePoint. They have to be sync'd locally. Excel, Word, and PowerPoint, and a few others, have been modified to open files directly on SharePoint."

Comment: Is there any other way to keep my Access file into a common path(except Shared Folder) and read, edit the file in the same path using python? I mean in a common path like Cloud or websites?

Comment: Please see the following page. Microsoft tell you how to do it with s split database architecture.https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/ways-to-share-an-access-desktop-database-03822632-da43-4d8f-ba2a-68da245a0446